# Match Data between 2 excel columns and show on screen result - Python

Tags: python

I have excel file with 2 columns ( A & B ) as below :

```
CODE   NAME

12     Jack

23     Mina

34     Ronaldo
```

I want to use Python. When user clicks to run the program, they must be enter 'CODE' and the program will show their name which found in NAME Column.. if they type wrong, the screen will show 'FAIL'

**Example**: If the user enters '12'.. the program will show "Hello Jack". If they type wrong... it will show "Pls try again".

I have some code as below, but when I run this code... it automatically shows 'FAIL' without taking input from the user.

Pls check and support me to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import sys
csv_file = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Read Data\file.csv"
file_ = StringIO(csv_file)
name_dict = dict([x for i, x in enumerate(csv.reader(file_)) if i>0])
print("Pls enter your employee ID")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print("hello {}".format(name_dict[sys.argv[-1]]))
    except KeyError as e:
        print("fail")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
# import libraries:
import pandas as pd

# path to csv file: (make sure column names are 'CODE' and 'NAME'):
path_to_csv_file = 'names.csv'

# load code names as pandas dataframe:
# note: pd.read_csv() will read integers as floats
code_names_dataframe = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file) 

# convert to dictionary:
code_names_dictionary = code_names_dataframe.to_dict(orient='records')

# infinite loop:
while True:

    # initialize variables:
    name = None

    # get user input from console:
    raw_user_input = input('Enter code: ')

    # convert user_input to float to match data type of code_names data:
    parsed_user_input = float(raw_user_input) 

    # iterate over code_names dictionary:
    for code_name in code_names_dictionary:

        # if the code exists, get the name:
        if code_name['CODE'] == parsed_user_input:
            name = code_name['NAME']

    # check if variable 'name' has been updated:        
    if name is not None:
        print('Hello ' + name)

        # break out of the while loop:
        break

    else:
        print('Please try again.')

# continue once code is correct:
print('I am outside the while loop!')
```

Comment: Hi Bro @Daniel Sokol. Pls check my post above. Thanks you!

Comment: Thanks you bro. If user input wrong CODE... the program will request user for re-inputting. How to do that ?

Comment: No problem! 1) Because of this line `if __name__ == '__main__'` this script will only execute if you launch this specific .py file - you can try removing this line to see if that solves your problem. 2) You can remove the `raise ValidationError()` line and instead have the function return a status like 0, then in main you can check the status and prompt the user to enter a new code if the status is 0. Let me know if you need some help with this.

Comment: Hi Bro @Daniel Sokol. I'm new with python. Sorry for that.  Could you pls make code in one main program, not divide def by def ?? I want to compare for learning.  Thanks you so much!

Comment: Sure, will do, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I've removed all of the functions, please let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: Thanks you so much Bro.. I want the program will continue if user input correctly their CODE... I want when user input correctly their CODE, it will break out of loop but not end program. Because the program will continue to ask something after user input correctly their CODE. Thanks you so much always!

Comment: Easy - all you need to do is add a `break` statement - I've added it to the code above. Please let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Hi Bro.  I have added 'break' before. But when user input correctly CODE, it will break out of loop but the program is end. How to avoid this ?

Comment: Because I want when user input correctly their CODE, the program will continue to ask something and then user continue to answer. In current program, when user input correctly CODE, it will end program. Sorry because disturb to you.

Comment: Thanks you Bro. I have understood and can do something by myself. Thanks you so much ^^

Answer (score -1):

I have edited and change path of my csv file as below code.
But when I run module... it not show screen for inputting 'CODE' .

```
import pandas as pd

def LoadCsvFile(path_to_csv_file):

# load code names as pandas dataframe:
# note: pd.read_csv() will read integers as floats
code_names = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file) 

# convert to dictionary:
code_names = code_names.to_dict(orient='records')

return code_names

def GetUserInput():

# get user input from console:
user_input = input('Enter code: ')

# convert user_input to float to match data type of code_names data:
user_input = float(user_input) 

return user_input

def LookUpCode(code, code_names):

# iterate over code_names dictionary:
for code_name in code_names:

    # if the code exists, return the name:
    if code_name['CODE'] == code:
        return code_name['NAME']

# if no code is found, raise error:
raise ValueError('[Error!] Invalid code.')

def main():

# 1) Load data from csv file:
path_to_csv_file = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Read Data\\file.csv'
code_names = LoadCsvFile(path_to_csv_file)

# 2) get user input:
user_input = GetUserInput()

# 3) look up user_input in code_names:
name = LookUpCode(user_input, code_names)
print('Hello %s' %name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # execute main:
    while True:
        main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w1f5.png)